# Injection java script file in Blazor project

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, blazor

I have the main file _layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I get 3 errors:

> Connection disconnected with error 'WebSocket is not in the OPEN state

> WebSocket is not in the OPEN state

> Failed to start the circuit.

**If the file is new, in the initial run the site will go up.**

**If the file already existed in the project, the site will not upload**

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you try to add it in the body part of  wwwroot/index.html file?

Comment: I do not have index.html in wwwroot. Should I create one like this?

Comment: are these all of the errors you are getting? if not then can post full error please?

Comment: In Blazor Server there's Pages/_Host.cshtml where this script should be added